# Can interact with views under my custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a custom view by using .xib. Then add it programatically into my view.
Here is the code to init view inside my custom view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Load the .xib
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];

        // Add as sub view
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is the code to add my custom view into a view:

```
CustomView *desView = [[CustomView alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:desView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:desView];
```

However, even the custom view is on top of other views but I still can interact with these views. I had tried to bring it to front but no use.

How can I disable interaction with those views but can still interact with my custom view?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: So you're trying to use this view to block taps to the views below?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I still want to interact with my custom view.

Comment: Just taps, or all gestures? Can you add another subview behind it that you can disable interaction on?

Answer (score 1):

Set this when you want to disable user interaction of the view you want.

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

or if you want to disable `desView`,

```
[desView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: I still want to enable interaction with my custom view so cannot disable it's interaction like that. I've just edited my question.

Comment: Do you have a map in the bottom view?

Comment: No, I don't. Just some views.